# 2 different values from same table in same query and group by date

Tags: mysql, sql

The output now in the table is correct for total bananas but for green bananas the output is the total every day. i want it to group total bananas and green bananas total sum per day for both.

```
SELECT bananas, date,

(SELECT COUNT(bananas) 
FROM banana_table
WHERE bananas = 'green')
AS green_bananas,

COUNT(bananas) AS total_bananas

FROM banana_table

GROUP BY date
```

Comment: you can see here regarding this question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198666/select-rows-from-table-having-two-specific-values

Comment: what is your table structure? where is the count of bananas to sum in the table?

Comment: Research conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT bananas, date,
       SUM( bananas = 'green' ) as green_bananas,
       COUNT(bananas) AS total_bananas
FROM banana_table
GROUP BY date;
```